# Can I access After effects recent animation presets sub-menu by script?

Tags: javascript, adobe, after-effects

The sub-menu of recent animation presets (attached) has the recent 20 presets used, can I get this list by scripting,
I simply want to add this list to a floating or docked pannel. but I can't find a way to access the data in this list.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMTmL.png)

I've searched the Ae's JS documentation but found no mention about this list